# Sobreescribir responsive.css en un tema hijo o child theme en wordpress?

Tags: css, wordpress

Estoy intentando sobreescribir un archivo css custom llamado responsive.css con temas hijos en wordpress.

Si edito el responsive.css del padre no hay problema pero si lo hago en el responsive.css hijo no funciona

El resto de los archivos (style.css) si funciona en el tema hijo pero responsive.css no funciona.

Comment: @blonfu es posible sí, quizá se ha dejado un } por cerrar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que debes hacer es añadir en el functions.php de tu tema hijo el reemplazo de este archivo:

```
function nombredemitemapadre_child_enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_dequeue_style( 'nombredemitemapadre-responsive' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'nombredemitemapadre-child-responsive', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/responsive.css' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'nombredemitemapadre_child_enqueue_scripts', 11 );
```

Si te fijas, en el action de `wp_enqueue_scripts` primero desregistro el responsive.css y acto seguido registro el nuevo

Comment: Muchas gracias, en cuanto tenga más tiempo lo pruebo :). Edito: No he visto errores en el código. Tiene que ser lo de functions.php

Comment: @DanielDíaz Una cosa. No se exactamente como se llama el handle del script que quiero desregistrar. Yo pongo nombredeltemapadre-responsive pero no parece que haga nada y para registrar el nuevo responsive.css no parece que esté funcionando.

Comment: Si haces `Control + U` verás el código fuente, y buscas `tuarchivo.css`, ese `<link>` tendrá un `id`, ese es el valor que te interesa